# Jquery dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not an expert with Jquery, my developer is unavailable . I am using https://jqcron.arnapou.net/demo/ . This works fine. The code is as follows,

```
    $(function(){
    $('.example7').jqCron({
        enabled_minute: true,
        multiple_dom: true,
        multiple_month: true,
        multiple_mins: true,
        multiple_dow: true,
        multiple_time_hours: true,
        multiple_time_minutes: true,
        default_period: 'week',
        default_value: '*/14 */2 */3 * *',
        bind_to: $('.example7-input'),
        bind_method: {
            set: function($element, value) {
                $element.val(value);
            }
        },
        no_reset_button: false,
        lang: 'en'
    });
});
```

The html

```
<div class="example7"></div> <input class="example7-input" />
```

**My problem**

I need to add the above function into a number of divs like as follows,

```
<div class="example7"></div> <input class="example7-input" />
<div class="example8"></div> <input class="example8-input" />

 <div class="example8"></div> <input class="example8-input" />
```

The solution is when click on **example7** div the value only need to apply to input box **example7-input** .  So each div need to show different values. All these use the same Jquery function.

So how can I modify the jQuery function

Comment: So you want to show `jqCron` on these three divs, don't you?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below snippet:

```
$(function () {
  var classes_arr = ["example7", "example8", "example9"];

  for (var item in classes_arr) {
    $("." + classes_arr[item] + "").jqCron({
      enabled_minute: true,
      multiple_dom: true,
      multiple_month: true,
      multiple_mins: true,
      multiple_dow: true,
      multiple_time_hours: true,
      multiple_time_minutes: true,
      default_period: "week",
      default_value: "*/14 */2 */3 * *",
      bind_to: $("." + classes_arr[item] + "-input"),
      bind_method: {
        set: function ($element, value) {
          $element.val(value);
        },
      },
      no_reset_button: false,
      lang: "en",
    });
  }
});
```

In this snippet all elements are grouped in an array. If you need to add more elements then add their class name in `classes_arr` array.

Comment: Updated answer. Check now.

Comment: Thank you Fraddy. This works fine. This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

So your function should be like this:

**`Javascript`**

```js
$(function () {
    $('.example7').jqCron({
        enabled_minute: true,
        multiple_dom: true,
        multiple_month: true,
        multiple_mins: true,
        multiple_dow: true,
        multiple_time_hours: true,
        multiple_time_minutes: true,
        default_period: 'week',
        default_value: '*/14 */2 */3 * *',
        bind_to: $('.example7-input, .example8-input, .example9-input'),
        bind_method: {
            set: function ($element, value) {
                $element.val(value);
            }
        },
        no_reset_button: false,
        lang: 'en'
    });
});
```

**`HTML`**

```html
<div class="example7"></div> <input class="example7-input" />
<div class="example8"></div> <input class="example8-input" />
<div class="example9"></div> <input class="example9-input" />
```

Comment: This apply  the values to all those input box. I mean if I change the value in one filed say example7 , then the jquery is applying that  change to all inputbox.

Comment: it is same as  above. The change is applying to all input field

Comment: I think I didn't get your problem. It would be better if you provide some input-output.

Comment: when click on example7 div the value only need to apply to input box example7-input . So each div need to show different values.